# Not getting expected results with the query I've in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

I have the following table structure that has day wise shifts.

At only **C** shift, time is shared by two days.

As you can *C* Shift starts at **20:30** and ends the next's days **06:00**.

The Table structure and data as follows

```
create table `machine_shifts` (
   `date` date ,
   `shift_start_time` time ,
   `shift_end_time` time ,
   `shift` varchar (60),
   `updated_on` timestamp 
);

insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-01','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-01','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-01','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-02','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-02','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-02','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-03','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-03','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-03','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-04','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-04','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-04','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:27');
```

The Data is represented as follows

[image]

Now what I wanted is, I want to retrieve the data between two given timelines which includes shift from the above data set. And I've this following query

```
SELECT * FROM machine_shifts
WHERE ((CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_start_time))
   BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00')
OR   (CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_end_time)
   BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00') 
ORDER BY `date`, shift_start_time ASC
```

With the above query, what I'm getting is [image]

In the above fetched result set, the last row wasn't expected and shouldn't be displayed also I want to retrieve C shift of 2010-01-01 too in the first row even though I'm passing 2010-01-02 00:00:00 as it should fall under C shift of 2010-01-01.
This is the following result I'm expecting
[image]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks fine; you just need a little bit of conditional logic to adjust the end date for the ends of shift C.

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM machine_shifts
WHERE 
    CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_start_time)
        BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' 
        AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00')
    OR CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_end_time) + INTERVAL (shift = 'C') DAY
        BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' 
        AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00'
ORDER BY `date`, shift_start_time ASC
```

The idea is to add one day to the computation when we met the end of a C shift. This is what expression `+ INTERVAL (shift = 'C') DAY` does.

Note that the nested parenthses around conditions are not needed here.

Comment: It was working with all the queries but except this 
BETWEEN '2010-01-01 07:01:00' AND '2010-01-01 14:00:00'
Could you help me out with it

Comment: Hi Could you check the above comment?

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada: I don't see a record in your sample data whose start or end time satisfy this condition...The first record has a start time *before* `'2010-01-01 07:01:00'` and an end time *after* `'2010-01-01 14:00:00'`.

Comment: My Bad for not mentioning this. But I thought it would work with this condition too . Should't it be satisfied in every test case?

Comment: Should I add another question for that case?