# MySQL Query isn't working in all the test cases

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table structure that has day wise shifts.

At only **C** shift, time is shared by two days.

As you can see *C* Shift starts at **20:30** and ends the next's days **06:00**.

The Table structure and data as follows

```
create table `machine_shifts` (
   `date` date ,
   `shift_start_time` time ,
   `shift_end_time` time ,
   `shift` varchar (60),
   `updated_on` timestamp 
);

insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-01','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-01','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-01','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-02','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-02','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-02','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-03','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-03','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-03','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-04','06:00:00','14:30:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-04','14:30:00','22:30:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26'),
('2010-01-04','22:30:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:27');
```

The Data is represented as follows

[image]

Now with the following query I'm achieve the data between the two date ranges. i.e between **'2010-01-02 00:00:00'** and **'2010-01-03 10:00:00'**.

```
SELECT * FROM machine_shifts
WHERE 
CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_start_time)
    BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00'
OR 
CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_end_time) + INTERVAL (shift = 'C') DAY
    BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00'
ORDER BY `date`, shift_start_time ASC
```

With the above query, what I'm getting is [image]

And this is the result set I expected very much.I could achieve this by posting another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122785/not-getting-expected-results-with-the-query-ive-in-mysql) earlier.
The above query works but it is working only when two dates are different but when ever I want to get the data between two different times within same date, I'm not getting expected data. Please find the following sample of date time ranges.
->  **'2010-01-01 07:01:00' AND '2010-01-01 14:00:00'**
With this I should the following expected data, but I'm getting empty result set.

[image]

I want the functionality of the above working query intact but also I should be getting data within a single day.

**Edit:** Just found that even in the above query there is problem with this range
**'2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 14:30:00'**

```
SELECT * FROM machine_shifts
WHERE 
CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_start_time)
BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 14:30:00'
OR 
CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_end_time) + INTERVAL (shift = 'C') DAY
BETWEEN '2010-01-02 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-03 14:30:00'
ORDER BY `date`, shift_start_time ASC
```

Here I'm getting [image]

Here I'm not expecting the last row at all.

How can I achieve it? Can you suggest me some better approach## Heading ##

Comment: Offhand, I believe you should be using unixtime to run that. Let me throw something together.

Comment: Can you run this to see what it yields?
SELECT * FROM machine_shifts
WHERE 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_start_time))
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-02 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-03 10:00:00')
OR 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_end_time)) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL (shift = 'C') DAY)
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-02 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-03 10:00:00')
ORDER BY `date`, shift_start_time ASC

Comment: Why would you expect to get shift B in your last output? It doesn't overlap the date range...

Comment: @Nick You are right. It was my bad. I've updated the question now. Could you look into it now.

Comment: @Akina Yes. That was wrong. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Akina answer is correct, but I would suggest using [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) to construct your dates rather than `CONCAT`

Comment: @Nick I've made an edit in the question.

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada did you try Akina's answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207514/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-korada-and-nick).

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive so if you use `14:30:00` as the time it will include shifts that start at that time

Comment: Can you change the data model? After all, a shift is from some date and time until some date and time, so shouldn't you store both start and end as timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM machine_shifts
WHERE CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_start_time) <= @end
AND
CONCAT(`date`, ' ', shift_end_time) + INTERVAL (shift = 'C') DAY >= @start
ORDER BY `date`, shift_start_time ASC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96e3f5bd0f5d8dd6b0087c0b2fafcaaf)

Two timeranges overlaps when both (the start of one range is less then the end of another range). Or "is not more than" for "overlapped or adjacent" variant as in my solution/fiddle.

Comment: I've checked in the fiddle with test cases. SET START:='2010 01 01 00:00:00'; SET END:='2010 01 01 14:30:00';
For this It's returning 2010-01-01 06:00:00 - 14:30:00 and 2010-01-01 14:30:00 - 22:30:00. Second row shouldn't be displayed. But also for the same inputs I'm expecting 2009-12-31 22:30:00 to  06:00 and 2010-01-01 06:00:00 to 14:30:00
Am I missed something

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8cc410fdaa866b152eb3aa8e8845a010) - everything is according your conditions. *Second row shouldn't be displayed.* Have you read the last sentence in my answer? If you need overlapped strongly, not adjacent, then correct the operators in WHERE conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in helping me Akina. It's working!!! Happy Programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Each machine shift is from some timestamp to another. In your data model, however, you only store the start timestamp - separated into date and time for no apparent reason - and an end time. This is not sufficient, as the DBMS cannot know which date the end time is supposed to be in. It is only in your head. You should have either an end datetime or a shift duration instead.

Best would be you changed your data model, so as to have start and end stored as datetimes or timestamps. If you cannot do that, let's create them on the fly in a `WITH` clause:

```
with shifts as
(
  select
    addtime(`date`, shift_start_time) as start_time,
    addtime(`date` + interval case when shift_end_time < shift_start_time then 1 else 0 end day,
           shift_end_time) as end_time,
    shift,
    updated on
  from machine_shifts
)
select *
from shifts
where start_time <= timestamp '2010-01-01 07:01:00' 
  and end_time >= timestamp '2010-01-01 14:00:00';
```

(On a side note: Be careful when adding a time to a date. MySQL doesn't do this properly and comes up with a wrong result. This is why I am ising `ADDTIME` instead of a mere `+` above.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> TIMEDIFF

```
select TIMEDIFF(cast(CONCAT('2010-01-01 ','06:00:00') as datetime),
cast(CONCAT('2010-01-01 ','14:30:00') as datetime));
```